# Celluloid 0.17.3 giving unexpected "undefined method" error

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I have started using Celluloid gem this morning for that first time. I am following this [Railscasts tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUUZP7Rpf1Y) and trying to figure things out.

I have a class called `"SomeClass"` and it has only one method. Here is the code:

```
require 'celluloid'

class SomeClass
  include Celluloid
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def assholify()
    puts "#{@name} has become an ASSHOLE."
  end
end
```

When I create new instances of the class and call its method (with a bang i.e. `"assholify!"`), I am getting the `undefined method 'assholify!'`, error. But Celluloid is supposed to trigger the method asynchronously when it is called with a bang. So here is how I am calling the method:

```
names = ['John', 'Tom', 'Harry']

names.each do |name|
  n = SomeClass.new name
  n.assholify!
end
```

Here is the full backtrace of the error:

```
I, [2016-09-09T11:28:02.488618 #3682]  INFO -- : Celluloid 0.17.3 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
/home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:42:in `rescue in check': undefined method `assholify!' for #<SomeClass:0x10897dc> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:39:in `check'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/call/sync.rb:16:in `dispatch'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:50:in `block in dispatch'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:76:in `block in task'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:339:in `block in task'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/task.rb:44:in `block in initialize'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/task/fibered.rb:14:in `block in create'
    from (celluloid):0:in `remote procedure call'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/call/sync.rb:45:in `value'
    from /home/railsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/proxy/sync.rb:22:in `method_missing'
    from some_class.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
    from some_class.rb:16:in `each'
    from some_class.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Why am I getting this error? Is it the right way to call the function? Also how do I get rid of `Celluloid 0.17.3 is running in BACKPORTED mode.` warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `undefined method` error occurred because actor methods are not called with a bang in the recent versions of celluloid gem. Instead you call the method like this: `n.async.assholify`. So here is what the code should look like:

```
names = ['John', 'Tom', 'Harry']

names.each do |name|
  n = SomeClass.new name
  n.async.assholify    # Instead of "n.assholify!"
end
```

---

For `"Celluloid 0.17.0 is running in BACKPORTED mode"` warning, take a look at [this wiki](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/DEPRECATION-WARNING). Backported Mode is the default, for a limited time. If you use  `require 'celluloid/current'` instead of `require 'celluloid'`, you should not see this warning.